# what is Module.prototype._compile function for?

Tags: node.js

When I run a node script to console log what `Module.prototype._compile` is:

```
const Module = require('module');
const compile = Module.prototype._compile;
console.log(compile);
```

the output is just: `[Function (anonymous)]`.
I can't see this documented anywhere, but I have came across it [in the wild](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-server-dom-webpack/src/ReactFlightWebpackNodeRegister.js)

Could someone give me an explanation of what this function is for and what it does, and/or point to where the docs are for it?

Comment: It's not [documented](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html) so can only assume it's an internal API

Comment: You can inspect the source code [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8a41d9b636be86350cd32847c3f89d327c4f6ff7/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L1324)

Comment: thanks. AFAICT it wraps the supplied file contents in an IIFE, passing exports, require, module, __dirname etc. into the scope, as well as setting the initial break point when `--inspect-brk` is set